# Secure email hosting service for a law firm

Tags: encryption, email, pgp, one-time-password, protonmail

I am looking for an email hosting service for a small law firm (4-5 accounts).
What i am looking for is:

- Possibility of sending password (or question/answer) encrypted message to a user outside of my hosting service
- Two factor authentication
- Possibility of using PGP encryption (not necessary)
- Messages being stored encrypted on the servers

All services that i found either don't provide function of sending password encrypted messages(msgsafe.io) or are expensive (60$ per user per year(startmail, hushmail), or 288 euro per year for 5 users(proton mail).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use PGP with standard Gmail. You can also set up 2FA. There are also plugins or Chrome extensions that help you enable it.

Comment: i failed to mention that i want to use my own domain. Can i do that with gmail ?

Comment: @Sackhorn you can do that with [GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com/) (a payed version of Gmail and friends, basically)

Comment: @Ángel that's good info - though it still works out at about $60 per user per year. I am not sure that you can get all of the above much cheaper.